# Thick black edges appear after coming out of sleep

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics, suspend

When my laptop comes out of sleep, there are thick black edges appear behind each window. This happens to all UI elements which cast a shadow, like some dropdowns an textbox suggestions.

These thick black edges do not go away until I restart laptop. I had upgraded from ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 when this problem started occurring. I have installed all updates, but still this issue persists. Has anyone faced this problem before and found any solution?

My laptop model is HP pavilion dv-7t 3000 and graphics card model is NVidia GeForce GT 230M (N10P-GE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug and a workaround is described on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1292830 (you can check it out for more details).

## Workaround

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (Warning: you will be sent to a text console where you won't be able to read this document).
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Once the workaround has been applied the problem no longer seems to occur on next suspend/resume.